# Transmitting data between components in Airflow

Tags: python, publish-subscribe, airflow

I am very new to Airflow and have read a large part of its documentation. From the documentations, I understand that small data between components in the DAG can be shared using XCom class. The component in the DAG which is publishing the data must push and the component which is subscribing to the data must pull.

However, I am not very clear on syntax part of pushing and pulling. I am referring to the section on XCom on the [documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html) and developed a code template. Suppose I have the following code which has only two components, a pusher and a puller. The pusher publishes the current time which the puller must consume and write to a log file.

```
from datetime import datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

log_file_location = '/usr/local/airflow/logs/time_log.log'

default_args = {'owner':'apache'}
dag = DAG('pushpull', default_args = default_args)

def push_function():
    #push this data on the DAG as key-value pair
    return(datetime.now()) #current time

def pull_function():
    with open(log_file_location, 'a') as logfile:
        current_time = '' #pull data from the pusher as key - value pair
        logfile.writelines('current time = '+current_time)
    logfile.close()

with dag:
    t1 = PythonOperator(
        task_id = 'pusher', 
        python_callable = push_function)

    t2 = PythonOperator(
        task_id = 'puller', 
        python_callable = pull_function)

    t2.set_upstream(t1)
```

I need help from Airflow masters here on two syntax:

1. How to push the data from push function along with a key
2. How to get the pull function pull the data using the key.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example to push to Xcom using a key:

```
def push_function(**context):
    msg='the_message'
    print("message to push: '%s'" % msg)
    task_instance = context['task_instance']
    task_instance.xcom_push(key="the_message", value=msg)
```

Example to pull to Xcom using a key:

```
def pull_function(**kwargs):
    ti = kwargs['ti']
    msg = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='push_task',key='the_message')
    print("received message: '%s'" % msg)
```

Example DAG:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

DAG = DAG(
  dag_id='simple_xcom',
  start_date=datetime(2017, 10, 26),
  schedule_interval=timedelta(1)
)

def push_function(**context):
    msg='the_message'
    print("message to push: '%s'" % msg)
    task_instance = context['task_instance']
    task_instance.xcom_push(key="the_message", value=msg)

push_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='push_task', 
    python_callable=push_function,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=DAG)

def pull_function(**kwargs):
    ti = kwargs['ti']
    msg = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='push_task',key='the_message')
    print("received message: '%s'" % msg)

pull_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='pull_task', 
    python_callable=pull_function,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=DAG)

push_task >> pull_task
```

Comment: Thanks  :)
I am now able to get the operators communicating.